# Unable to draw rectangle over imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, crop

I am Getting a problem drawing rectangle over imageview. Here is the peace of code. Xml is also there . my whole concern is if we can draw rect over imageview.??

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.cropimage);
            paint=new Paint();
            bobj = new BaldBooth1();
            bm = BaldBooth1.bMap;
            d = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            iv = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image));
            iv.setImageDrawable(d);
            createRectInView(iv);

            ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next)).setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        public void createRectInView(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            canvas=new Canvas();
            canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 80, 80, paint);
            v.draw(canvas);


        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cropping image using rect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443300/cropping-image-using-rect)

Comment: So ..?? i there any problem ha..?? No One Answered there so have posted it this way..F>O

Comment: A little easily offended, are we? And yes, stop spamming questions. If you don't get any answers, it's probably because you have not given it enough time (1 hour is often not enough) or your question lacks some quality *(which it does, almost no explanation what exactly you are trying to do; if no one can figure out what you want, they can't help you)*.

Comment: what's wrong with that question .. go check it out.. and sometime we dont have time.. and yes i delete such questions for your reference..if you have that much time.. waste it on solving my problem

Comment: I checked it, I told you whats wrong. And I won't reward your spamming by answering your questions. Post a quality one the first time instead and edit details into that when you get something new to post. Then I will answer if I can help you. The question will get pushed to the frontpage with an edit anyway.

Comment: Will TC of this from next Time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `createRectInView(View v)` does not draw a rectangle over ImageView, it just create a canvas, draw a rectangle on that canvas, then draw the content of ImageView on that canvas, so it does not do what you expect.

Here is one possible resolution: you can extend ImageView and override its onDraw() method, for example..

```
public class ExtendedImageView extends ImageView {
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 80, 80, paint);
    }
}
```

Updated:

Hi arun, I just test the code, and it works fine. Here are the details: for example, you can create the ExtendedImageView in package com.abc.widget, so in your cropImage.xml file, replace the `<ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">`  to `<com.abc.widget.ExtendedImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">`. As you see, you only need to change the class name. Then changed the `onCreate()` method as:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.cropimage);
            bobj = new BaldBooth1();
            bm = BaldBooth1.bMap;
            d = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            iv = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image));
            iv.setImageDrawable(d);
            ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next)).setOnClickListener(this);

        }
```

Comment: Hmm... Yes you're right in your part .but i tried your solution it did nt work either. may be i am doing it in a wrong way can u please elaborate

Comment: 02-25 18:42:24.203: E/AndroidRuntime(4013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.baldbooth1/com.my.baldbooth1.CropImage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.my.baldbooth1.ExpandableImageView

Comment: This Error is generated when i am done with changes. u can see the rect drawn over imageview when u tried..??

Comment: yeah I can see the rect, but I directly add the ExtendedImageView in code rather than in xml layout files. If you xml layout files are correct, maybe cleaning the project will solve this inflating problem.

Comment: Here is what I do in onCreate() method of activity: ExtendedImageView imageView = new ExtendedImageView(this);
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
        viewGroup.addView(imageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.theme);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.my.baldbooth1.ExpandableImageView Popping up.. no idea what to do..

Comment: this is my oncreate  ExpandableImageView imageView = new ExpandableImageView(this);
  setContentView(R.layout.cropimage);
  paint = new Paint();
  bobj = new BaldBooth1();
  bm = BaldBooth1.bMap;
  d = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
  // iv = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image));
  // iv.setImageDrawable(d);
  // createRectInView(((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlUpper)));
  // createRectInView(iv);
  ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next)).setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: This is what i have placed in on Draw  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  Log.i(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Inside onDraw");
     Paint paint = new Paint();
         paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
         canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 80, 80, paint);
}

 public ExpandableImageView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

Comment: oops.. the <com.abc.widget.ExtendedImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> should be <com.abc.widget.ExtendedImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> , i didn't notice that.

Comment: this is the XML                                                                               <com.my.baldbooth1.ExpandableImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" />

Comment: Hahahaha..don't woory i already had done with this.. i know how to close tabs sir.

Comment: I noticed that seems you only have one constructor in you ExpandableImageView, you should probably also add the other two: public ExpandableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
 }

 public ExpandableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
 }

Comment: u got it man... now it seems working i mean not crashing but still i can see rect drwn anywhere ...

Comment: the rect should be black, make sure that your image is not having the similar color so that u can easily find it. :)